Calculate new center of rectangle when line connecting the center updates
This is an SVG application. I have a line with centerPoint, startPoint, endPoint, and angle properties. I have a rectangle that has a centerPoint, width and height. From that I can calculate the four corners of rectangles.
I am placing my rectangle on a line. The rectangles center is on any point of line.
Now I have a use case that my line can be dragged using either start or end point. I could click and drag the end point and move around any direction. My lines angle, start or end point, center point gets changed.
I want my rectangle to be connected with the line, when line dragging is happening.
interface IPoint{
  x: number,
  y: number,
}
class Line {
startPoint: IPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };
endPoint: IPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  centerPoint: IPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  angle: number = 0;
}

export class Rectangle {
  centerPoint: IPoint;
  height: number;
  width: number;
  angle: number;
  offset: IPoint;
  lineDisplacement: { 
    dx: number; 
    dy: number 
  };
}`

What I tried is to calculate the difference between rectangle center and line center:
getDisplacement(p1: IPoint, p2: IPoint) {
  return {
    dx: p2.x - p1.x,
    dy: p2.y - p1.y
  };
}

rectangle.lineDisplacement = this.getDisplacement(
  line.centerPoint,
  rectangle.centerPoint
);

I am doing this when I am creating the rectangle on any point on line, and keep that value on rectangle as lineDisplacement. Then I tried to update the rectangle center, when line center changed and angle with line's new angle.
const newCenter = {
  x: line.midPoint.x + rectangle.lineDisplacement.dx,
  y: line.midPoint.y + rectangle.lineDisplacement.dy
};

rectangle.setCenter(newCenter);
rectangle.setAngle(line.getAngle);

This gets close, but the new center is never on line. It works only if line's angle has not been changed. I have tried other approaches which use Math.cos and Math.sin, but that was nowhere near the line. So I am lost now currently.
Thanks in advance for any direction.

Can you please show a full working example of your code. It's much easier to debug something we can see, instead of trying to piece it together from disjointed snippets

I am on it. Will edit the question and add it.

Providing full working examples have become challenging due to lots of bits and pieces being here and there

So (base) line always is central line of rectangle?

Yes. Want to have that.

I don't know if you find this useful, but instead of calculating the position, maybe you can use a <marker>. I guess it depends on the complexity of the SVG. As an example the marker is not clickable, so if that is a requirement, this approach might not be the ideal solution.
The line displacement can be adjusted using the refX attribute on the marker.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200">
  <line marker-start="url(#square)" x1="5" y1="20" x2="95" y2="50" stroke="green" />
  <defs>
    <marker id="square" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="40" refY="5" markerWidth="10"
      markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
      <rect width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>
</svg>



